# Error: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! when read JSON data using for loops

Tags: php, json, twitter

I am creating a webapp that gathers all comment of twitter users about some keyword (in PHP), and I using this URL: http://search.twitter.com/search.json.

Problem is: I use for loop to retrieve all comments, and when it comes to page 21, it throws this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://search.twitter.com/search.json?page=21&max_id=254777971188039680&q=love&rpp=100&result_type=mixed): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in C:\xampp\htdocs\cs2\action.php on line 30
```

However, if I access above link (http://search.twitter.com/search.json?page=21&max_id=254777971188039680&q=love&rpp=100&result_type=mixed) by entering that url to Addressbar of browser and it still returns result!

So, why this link can be accessed directly by browser but can't be read by `file_get_contents` function?

//added code:

```
<?php
    $keyword1 = $_POST["key"];
    $keyword = str_replace(' ', '%20',$keyword1);
    $url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=$keyword&rpp=100&result_type=mixed";
    $json_string = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($json_string);
    $olddata = $data;
    $size = count($data->{"results"});
    $_SESSION["dem"] = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < $size;$i++){
        echo($data->{"results"}[$i]->{"text"}."<br/>");
        $_SESSION["dem"]++;
    }
    while(true){
        try{
        sleep(0.01);
        $url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json".$olddata->{"next_page"};
        if(strcmp($url,"http://search.twitter.com/search.json") == 0) break;
        $json_string = file_get_contents($url);
        $data = json_decode($json_string);
        $olddata = $data;
        $size = count($data->{"results"});
        for($i = 0; $i < $size;$i++){
            echo($data->{"results"}[$i]->{"text"}."<br/>");
            $_SESSION["dem"]++;
        } 
        }
        catch(Exception $e){

            break;
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Sure you are not sending a large number of request to th Twitter API?

Comment: You are probably sending requests too fast.

Comment: I use for loop to retrieve data, it stop getting data from search.twitter.com/search.json since 21st loop. Because there are many result from twittersearch, so I have to use loop.

Comment: @steve: Should I add a sleep(1) at the end of each loop?

Comment: @MrYanDao: I added my code in my question above :)

Comment: Does the code works for the first few times when you run it? sleep(0.01) is too little. This probably caused you to run out of API request.

Comment: @MrYanDao: As I said, it loop 20times, and at 21st loop, it cant access the URL any more!